# Comparing RDBM's with a Java application

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, firebird

I am buiding an application in Java that connects to a variety of databases, MySQL, Oracle, Firebird and a few others. The user (me) can select a test for that connection (Not sure if I should predefine the tests or just allow a free form text box for the user to input a statement.)

The plan is to try the application(client) on a ubuntu, solaris and Windows 7 machine (I will infact be rebuilding a home computer several times).

On the server side I will be installing each RDBMS on a Windows, Ubuntu and Solaris Server.

The idea is I would like to collate some data on the RDBMS/Operating System client-side and server-side, times etc....

What I could use some help with is generating some informative tests. Ideally I would like them to mock a a real world enviroment. Seeing as I am using two-tier architecture and have no idea how I would go about implementing a buisness layer I would appreciate some thoughts on what kinds of tests I should run.

The application will be able to mock multiple users accessing the database so please be ruthless.

On a side note any thoughts on the scope... more o.s, rdbms suggestions would be great!

Kind regards

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't trying to write a whole benchmarking app yourself...

There are two tools that work well if it's a web app connecting to the database:

ab (apache bench) which is on every unix machine I've used in the past 4 years.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

And jmeter:
http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: I am creating the application for my own practice and for university.